# Haskell generate XML method

Tags: xml, haskell, generator

I'm new in Haskell and start to write simple XML generator library.

I want to ask Haskell Guru, which is capable of generating XML in particular the right to the point of view of functional programming and Haskell language? Maybe write simple DSL or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, your English is a little difficult to understand -- are you wanting to do this as an exercise, or find a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an existing library, such as HaXmL, [xmlgen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlgen), or one of the many other XML generator libraries: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:xml

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. I guess English is not your first language.  Can you change your question to make it clearer?  Try breaking the long sentence into single ideas.